# Handling rejected HTTP responses with status 401

Tags: javascript, beginner, error-handling, angular.js

I'm kinda new to javascript and have question about it. Now my practical project is growing a bit bigger. I got the following if else statement. Is it possible to refactor this ? Should i use an use case or are there other options or will this decrease the loading speed of the application.

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .factory('HttpResponseInterceptor', HttpResponseInterceptor);

    HttpResponseInterceptor.$inject = ['$q','$location'];
    function HttpResponseInterceptor($q,$location) {

        return {
            response: function(response){
                if (response.status === 401) {

                }
                return response || $q.when(response);
            },
            responseError: function(rejection) {



                if(rejection.status ===401 && rejection.config.url === "user") {
                    console.log("Check")
                }
                else if (rejection.status ===401 &&  rejection.config.url == "l18n/fr_FR.json")
                {
                    console.log("Check2")
                }
                else if (rejection.status ===401 &&  rejection.config.url == "l18n/nl_NL.json")
                {
                    console.log("Check2")
                }
                else if (rejection.status ===401 &&  rejection.config.url == "l18n/de_DE.json")
                {
                    console.log("Check2")
                }
                else if (rejection.status ===401 &&  rejection.config.url == "l18n/es_ES.json")
                {
                    console.log("Check2")
                }
                else if (rejection.status ===401 &&  rejection.config.url == "l18n/en_US.json")
                {
                    console.log("Check2")
                }
                else
                {
                    $location.path('/login');
                }


               /* if (rejection.status === 401 && rejection.config.url !== "user") {

                    $location.path('/login');
                }*/
                return $q.reject(rejection);
            }
        };

    }

})();
```

Comment: As we all want to make our code more efficient or improve it in one way or another, try to write a title that summarizes what your code does, not what you want to get out of a review. For examples of good titles, check out [Best of Code Review 2014 - Best Question Title Category](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/3883/23788) You may also want to read [How to get the best value out of Code Review - Asking Questions](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/2438/41243).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd actually go a bit further than `janos`. He is perfectly right in that by repeatedly checking `rejection.status`, you're repeating yourself in code. Repeatedly checking the variable against multiple values makes this a perfect candidate for a `switch` statement:

```
responseError: function(rejection) {
    if (rejection.status === 401) {
        switch (rejection.config.url) {
            case "user":
                console.log("Check");
                break;
            case "l18n/fr_FR.json":
            case "l18n/nl_NL.json":
            case "l18n/de_DE.json":
            case "l18n/es_ES.json":
            case "l18n/en_US.json":
                console.log("Check2");
                break;
            default:
                $location.path('/login');
                break;
        }
    }

    return $q.reject(rejection);    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't repeat yourself. The repeated checks on `rejection.status ===401` are clearly pointless.
Rewrite in a way to check this condition only once, for example by nesting the other conditions:

```
if (rejection.status === 401) {
  if (rejection.config.url === "user") {
    console.log("Check")
  }
  else if (rejection.config.url == "l18n/fr_FR.json")
  {
    console.log("Check2")
  }
  else if (rejection.config.url == "l18n/nl_NL.json")
  {
    console.log("Check2")
  }
  //
  // ... more checks
  //
  else
  {
    $location.path('/login');
  }
} else
{
  $location.path('/login');
}
```

Comment: You're better off with a guard clause at the top to handle the non-401 case.  That way the large if...else can be handled without nested indentation.